# How to resize the `container` automatically when more text is fed to the `textbox`?

Tags: flutter

How to resize the `container` automatically when more text is fed to the `textbox`? I have used `ellipsis` or `maxlines` etc and I `don't wanna truncate text`. I just wanna parent container to increase the height on `overflow` according to the height of the textbox.

```
Container(
                     width: 100,
                    height: 200,
                  child: Text(
                        'some lonnnggggg texxttttttt',
                        style: widget.textStyle,
                         
                      ),
                    ),
```

[image]

Comment: Set the width according to your will but remove the height so when more text will come into the container it will automatically adjust its height itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Container fit the child so just remove the height propertie.